# How to use jfrog cli to upload to Artifactory using group artifactid version classifier and packaging

Tags: java, maven, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I've been using "mvn deploy" to publish a group of tar.gz files to Artifactory. I give it the group, artifactId, version, packaging and classifier along with the path and filename of the file to upload and it publishes the bytes in the file into the Artifactory maven 2 repo alongside of the jar/war and pom.

The jar/war and pom were put there by "mvn clean deploy" or "gradle artifactoryPublish" (etc) or even "jfrog rt mvn "clean install". The later one uses the jfrog cli tool to run maven and do the publishing of the jar/war and pom. The former uses maven directly. And the middle one uses gradle to publish.

I've been publishing all these files to show up in the same "folder" inside Artifactory. That's what I still want to happen with the jfrog cli tool.

Each of the tar.gz files has the same group, artifactid and version and those also match the same attributes of the jar/war and pom that maven gets from the pom.xml. Packaging is 'tar.gz' for all the tar.gz files and each has a unique classifier like dev, test, stage or prod.

Now I want to use the jfrog cli to upload the tar gz files instead of maven. And I tried something like this which I created by building the 5 maven coordinates into a destination repository path/file:

```
jfrog rt upload ~/workspace/target/tmptargz-dev.tar.gz dev-releases/com/myCompany/myTeam/myWAR/0.12.3-d0fa9d2/myWAR-0.12.3-d0fa9d2-config-dev.tar.gz/ '--props=' '--build-name=myWAR' '--build-number=0.12.3-d0fa9d2'
```

The code to build the target (from my Jenkinsfile) looks like this:

```
String target = "${repoName}/${group}/${artifactId}/${version}/${artifactId}-${version}${classifier}.${packaging}"
```

But it takes the 'target' as being a folder only (even though I included what I wanted the filename to be) and leaves the filename unchanged so I can download the file with a curl from here:

```
https://artifacts.mycompany.com/artifactory/dev-releases/com/myCompany/myTeam/myWAR/0.12.3-d0fa9d2/myWAR-0.12.3-d0fa9d2-config-dev.tar.gz/tmptargz-dev.tar.gz
```

Note that what I wanted the filename to be is the last component of the path and the temp filename follows that.

Q: So how do I upload to Artifactory using the 5 maven coordinates to build the "jfrog rt upload" command? Is there an more sane way than having to rename the file first?

I would be happy to use a file descriptor if that makes it easier. Or we can just put the arguments on the command line.

Comment: It looks like your target path ends with a slash. The slash is an indication to jfrog-cli that the last path component is a folder that should be crated in Artifactory. Please try removing the trailing slash, so that jfrog-cli uploads the file with the name specified as the last path component. I would also recomment looking into using File Specs, to avoid running a separate upload command for each file. See the jfrog-cli online documentation.

Comment: @EyalBenMoshe Make an answer and I'll check it.

Comment: I switched to a file spec with pattern as the 1st parameter after 'upload' and target as the 2nd parameter but without the final slash. It works. Then I added all the files into a single file spec and they all uploaded in one fell swoop. Perfect. (It's almost embarrassing to miss that trailing slash.)

Comment: That's great to hear! Thanks for confirming! You can add this as an answer here. This may help others.